# Android Studio Gradle project refresh failed Error:Connection reset

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting below error while importing the project in Android Studio. But my existing projects are working fine.

**Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed
Error:Connection reset**

Tried following workarounds.

1. Deleted .gradle and restarted AS.
2. Invalidate cache and restarted AS.
3. Updated gradle tool
4. Updated SDK
5. Updated Android Studio
6. Checked the versions gradle script
7. Restarted System :|

Please help.

Comment: Can you paste exact error and where do you get it, in Gradle Console

Comment: @OlegBogdanov This is the error:  Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed Error:Connection reset

Comment: @Mani Try running gradle in debug mode, maybe you get a more detailed error. (Preferences -> Compiler -> Command-line Options)